# housing construction on a (google) map

Tags: google-maps, interactive

For a new housing project, a complete area will be developed on a blank piece of land. We would like to create a nice interactive chart with all the different sub housing projects. Currently we have a static map available, but want to turn this into an interactive map.

Currently we have found zeemaps.com to add pointers to the map, highlight new building area's and add additional information. One thing is lagging, is the ability to create roads/parks in the map.

Are there any tools out there available where I can 'draw' the new to be developed area into a google-like map.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to create a set of custom map tiles that replace or overlay the standard map tiles for your development area, see 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes

You might even be able to create custom streetview images to create a virtual drive though of the development and the inside of the buildings, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomStreetView

Answer (score 0):

Is Google Map Maker https://www.google.co.uk/mapmaker enabled for your area?
This would allow you to add all the roads, buildings parks in your development.

Note: You would need to check the terms of use to ensure that adding planned but not yet built developments was permitted, but I do see that you can set the construction status of a road to Planned so I assume it is OK.

You can also do similar editing with Open Street map https://www.openstreetmap.org

Comment: Mymsman thanks for the suggestion. I found the google mapmaker, but as you pointed out correctly the terms of use are not in my favour. The roads are still not 100% definited, but planned roads are not shown on the map.